# Multiple Step Registration Form PHP/MySql using sessions

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, registration

I'm trying to implement a two-step registration form for my site wherein I used 2 separate pages in order to get the information from the user.

**First Step:**

```
if($submit)
{
    $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
    mysql_select_db("mydb");
    $queryreg = mysql_query("INSERT INTO volunteerbio VALUES (<my insert values>)");
}
//gets the latest id added
$query = mysql_query("SELECT MAX(volunteerID) FROM volunteerbio");
$numrows = mysql_num_rows($query);

if($numrows!=0)
{
    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
    {
        $dbaccountID = $row['volunteerID'];
    }
    header("Location: http://localhost/RedCrossCaloocan/registration2_volunteer.php");
    $_SESSION['volunteerID']=$dbaccountID;
}
}
?>
```

**What the first step does is that it creates a complete table row wherein the values needed for the second step will be temporarily left with blank values until they are updated in the next step.**

**Second Step:**

```
<?php
  session_start();
  $idnum = @$_SESSION['volunteerID'];
  $connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
  mysql_select_db("mydb");

if($submit)
{
  $updateSkills = mysql_query("

     UPDATE volunteerbio
     SET medicalSkillRating = $medicalRating,
         electronicsSkillRating = $electronicRating,
         errandSkillRating = $errandRating,
         childCareSkillRating = $childCareRating,
         counsellingSkillRating = $counsellingRating,
         officeSkillRating = $officeRating,
         communicationSkillRating =$communicationRating,
         carpentrySkillRating = $carpentryRating
     WHERE volunteerID = $idnum;

     ");
  }
?>
```

**The second step basically updates the fields which where filled with blank values during the first step in order to complete the registration.**

The first step already works and is able to add the values to the database however, I am having a problem on updating the blank values through the second step.

I have a feeling that there may be a problem regarding my usage of sessions in order to get the newly generated ID from the first step, but I just can't figure it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing:

```
header("Location: http://localhost/RedCrossCaloocan/registration2_volunteer.php");
$_SESSION['volunteerID']=$dbaccountID;
```

The second line MAY never get executed, because you do a redirect before it. I say MAY because it MAY get executed. You have to add `exit();` after all redirects to prevent further execution of the script.

Another thing:

Never suppress warnings in PHP using `@`. The `@` is almost never needed. So instead of doing:

```
@$_SESSION['volunteerID'];
```

You should do:

```
if (isset($_SESSION['volunteerID'])) {
    $idnum = $_SESSION['volunteerID'];
} else {
    // something went wrong???
}
```

I can't see it in your example, but do prevent SQLi vulnerabilities?

Comment: Managed to fix it. Seems I had to change some names when I used the MAX. Thanks for the help and great coding advice!